# Wordpress Unable Upload theme

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

I have a problem regarding to theme upload when I want to upload custom theme to my local wordpress site.

It says

Unable to create directory wp-content/2017/06. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

my site location is in this folder.

/home/nginx/wordpress/

I use nginx, serving on port 8003.

any Idea of anything I should do ? because in mysql database I have changed the wp_option -> upload_path to /home/nginx/wordpress/wp-content/

thanks for the help :)

Comment: You'll want to know what user php is running as. Also, check that the folder  exists and has the correct file-permissions (often 644 for files and 755 for directories) if php & thereby wordpress is logged in to the server as Guest, they're not going to be able to do the admin-stuff they need to.

Comment: But hopefully you can just change the file-permissions and you'll be all set.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to upload a theme into the media (uploads) directory (based on the date values appended) - The destination folder for themes is ../wp-content/themes/. Please see - https://codex.wordpress.org/Themes. Of course you should verify your permissions as described above.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the answers, very much appreciated.  okay, now I already changed the permissions into chmod a+rw to the root folder, change the upload without based on date values. But it still shows error like this one "Unable to create directory wp-content. Is its parent directory writable by the server?" without date. @admcfajn